# Getting http error 401: Unauthorized when processing oauth_token and oauth_verifier

Tags: twitter-oauth

Can someone please help with this. Thanks in advance.

I send request to twitter with nonce, callback_url, consumer_key, etc. Twitter then prompts the user to enter login and password. User successfully enters login credentials. After that Twitter sends oauth_token and oauth_verifier to the callback URl specified in the earlier call. But now I always get 'HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized' error. Can someone please help with this? Have spent days on it. Thank you.

"GET /account/twitter/oauthacc?oauth_token=ererererer&oauth_verifier=ereret43rwererererer"

```
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File 
 "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 714, in __call__handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test/2-7.3629731/oauth.py", line 74, in get
    self.mOauthRequestToken = vOauthApi.getRequestToken(self.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~-test/2-7.369731/libs/oauthtwitter.py", line 206, in getRequestToken
    resp = self._FetchUrl(url, no_cache=True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test/2-7.3639731/libs/oauthtwitter.py", line 118, in _FetchUrl
    url_data = opener.open(url).read()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 387, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 498, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 425, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 506, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```